# How to monitor the output of IPMI SOL for a particular word, then echo a phrase?

Tags: bash, ipmi

I am trying to find a way to monitor IPMI SOL output for a particular word/phrase, then echo something.

Basically, I am wanting to create a script that can be passed a list of server names, will loop through each of them, open an IPMI SOL session, and look for the word "login:", then close the session.  If the word is found, I plan to echo something like "$server is available for login".

Is monitoring the output of IPMI SOL for a script possible?  Is it possible to use a script to send keystrokes to SOL (because sometimes SOL doesn't refresh the pane unless enter is pressed)?  I apologize for asking what may be a trivial question, but my experience with IPMI is limited.

Comment: Task like this can be usually solved easily with expect: https://core.tcl-lang.org/expect/index

Comment: Is there a way to do this without expect?

Comment: Sure there is a way, but with expect it is much easier.